# ASP.NET MVC - Using HTML Helpers in RAZOR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC RAZOR View. This view had the following:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
```

That approach was working fine. But, I needed to add a check on the  name field.So I started using:

```
@if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Name)
{
  <b>The name wasn't provided</b>
}
else
{
  Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name);
  <div>the name should appear</div>
}
```

Now, my label isn't appearing at all. In some cases, I'll see the "The name wasn't provided" like I expected. But, when a name is present, I see "the name should appear", but I do not see the actual name like I'd expect.

What am I doing wrong? It seems odd that just `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)` worked as expected. But, once I added the check, it didn't.

Comment: I hope it solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name);
  <div>the name should appear</div>
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know you needed the `@` when it was in a block like that.

Comment: @user687554 you do apparently

Answer (score 0):

You have missed @ before Html.LabelFor

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `@` symbol to `Html` part in the else section of your if statement:

```
@if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Name)
{
     <b>The name wasn't provided</b>
}
else
{
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name);
     <div>the name should appear</div>
}
```